# How to detect if gson.fromjson() has excess elements

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm currently making a class that tests if the gson classes I generated are still up to date, this means I have to detect if any of the json elements have changed, deleted or added. Let's say I have a json which is simply

```
{
  "FloatingText": {
        "Dodge_Enabled": false,
        "foo": false
    },
    "General": {
        "something": false,
        "somethingelse": false
    }
}
```

And the class for floatingtext has the following fields:

```
@SerializedName("Dodge_Enabled")
@Expose
public Boolean dodgeEnabled;
```

Now the foo field is obviously missing here, my question is how to find out how I can detect this reliably even when the json is about a thousand times bigger. The gson documentation states that it should throw a exception when the json doesn't match the class but it doesn't and after some research it only throws it when the type is heavily malformed so that's off the table.

The code I have now checks correctly for missing or changed fields but not for new ones

```
        GameSettings gameSettings = gson.fromJson(json, GameSettings.class);
    for (Field declaredField : gameSettings.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        declaredField.setAccessible(true);
        Object object = declaredField.get(gameSettings);
        if (object == null && !Modifier.isStatic(declaredField.getModifiers())) {
            Assert.fail();
        }

        for (Field declaredSubfield : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            declaredSubfield.setAccessible(true);
            Object subObject = declaredSubfield.get(object);
            if (subObject == null && !Modifier.isStatic(declaredSubfield.getModifiers())) {
                System.out.println("Processing went wrong at: " + declaredSubfield + "\n Json: " + json);
                Assert.fail();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: "The gson documentation states that it should throw a exception when the json doesn't match the class"

Where exactly does it say that?

Comment: It actually says `Throws:JsonSyntaxException - if json is not a valid representation for an object of typeclassOfT`. There is some room for interpretation as to what constitutes a _valid_ representation. If the JSON contains more data than required to construct a class, simply skipping the superfluous data will still leave you with a valid representation of your original class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is to deserialize the incoming JSON, then serialize it again and check if the result matches your incoming JSON:

```
GameSettings settings = gson.fromJson( json, GameSettings.class );

String exportedJson = gson.toJson( settings );
if ( !exportedJson.equals( json ) )
{
    Assert.fail();
}
```

This would of course be prone to raise alarms if someone modified the previously exported JSON by hand and changed something about the pretty-printing. But if it's just about raising an alert for the dev to check, it might be enough.

If you wanted to output more information about what exactly is different in the external representation, you could use a library that detects diffs:

- https://github.com/java-diff-utils/java-diff-utils
- https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch